# Android NDK facilities

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a little experience with Android SDK, but don't know anything about NDK. And i want ask some questions about NDK to people who works with it.

Android dalvik VM have memory restrictions, such as one process cannot have heap size more than 16/24/32 Mb. But in my application i want use a little more memory. Can i create with NDK object that more than max dalvik heap size?

I wanna work with bitmap images in NDK. Does NDK have any libraries for it?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android NDK allows writing code not subject to the memory limits of the Dalvik VM heap limits, so you can allocate more memory than from within Dalvik. The device you are using may not support large allocations however e.g. take care to not exceed whatever limits the hardware and the OS enforce.

As for NDK libraries, the C++ STL and a subset of the C std libraries and some subset of the Posix APIs are provided, plus a few Android specific APIs. See [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#tools) for an overview, and the documentation with the NDK for details.